# Google Cloud Function succeeds, but not showing expected output

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions

I am testing out cloud function and I have things setup, but output is not populating correctly (the output is not being saved into Cloud Storage and my print statements are not populating).  Here is my code and my requirements below.  I have setup the Cloud Function to just run as a HTTP request trigger type with unauthenticated invocations and having a Runtime service account as a specified account that has write access to Cloud Storage.  I have verified that I am calling the correct Entry point.

logs

```
2022-03-22T18:52:02.749482564Z test-example vczj9p85h5m2 Function execution started
2022-03-22T18:52:04.148507183Z test-example vczj9p85h5m2 Function execution took 1399 ms. 
Finished with status code: 200
```

main.py

```
import requests
from google.cloud import storage
import json

def upload_to_gsc(data):
    print("saving to cloud storage")
    client = storage.Client(project="my-project-id")
    bucket = client.bucket("my-bucket-name")
    blob = bucket.blob("subfolder/name_of_file")
    blob.upload_from_string(data)
    print("data uploaded to cloud storage")

def get_pokemon(request):
    url = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=100&offset=200"
    data = requests.get(url).json()
    output = [i.get("name") for i in data["results"]]
    data = json.dumps(output)
    upload_to_gsc(data=data)
    print("saved data!")
```

requirements.txt

```
google-cloud-storage
requests==2.26.0
```

Comment: Your exact code sample seems to work for me with a service account with **Storage Object Admin** permissions. I did however add a return statement of `return "Success", 200` to the `get_pokemon` function. I would recommend double-checking your project-id and bucket names etc and that you have get_pokemon as your entrypoint (make sure you didn't by accident set upload_to_gcs as entrypoint). You could also try debugging with logging, https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/python

Comment: Hey @JackWotherspoon unfortunately, after double checking my entry point, project-id, and bucket name.  I am still unable to get the Cloud Function to behave properly.   I am not sure if its a setup issue I am having or what the issue is, when I look at the logs of the cloud function I don't see any errors.

Comment: I have recreated the Cloud Function and it seems to be working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JackWotherspoon mentioned, be sure to make sure you double check your project-id,bucket-name and entry point if you have a case like I did.  For myself, I recreated the Cloud Function and tested it and it worked again.

Answer (score 0):

As @dko512 mentioned in comments, issue was resolved by recreating and redeploying the Cloud Function.

Posting the answer as community wiki for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.

Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.